# PHP MySQL join one table with another one but twice

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I'm trying to join two tables but the last one twice.
What I've got is this:

```
Table 1
    id name email
    476 Lars Lyngsoe   test@test.test
    478 Lars2 Lyngsoe2 test2@test2.test2
    495 Lars3 Lyngso3  test3@test3.test3

Table 2
    user_id  profile_key      profile_value
    476     'profile.klasse'  '10A'
    495     'profile.klasse'  '10B'
    476     'profile.phone'   '12345678'
    478     'profile.klasse'  '10A'
    478     'profile.phone'   '23432123'
    495     'profile.phone'   '21212143'
```

Where id in Table 1 equals user_id in Table 2

I've tried to join and make subqueries but nothing works.
What I want to achieve is this:

```
Table
    id  name           email              class  phone
    476 Lars Lyngsoe   test@test.test     '10A'  '12345678'
    478 Lars2 Lyngsoe2 test2@test2.test2  '10A'  '23432123' 
    495 Lars3 Lyngso3  test3@test3.test3  '10B'  '21212143'
```

Thank's for your help.

Lars

Comment: Include the queries you've tried in your question.

Comment: Where did you get the phone number?

Comment: instead of joining twice invert the join so table 2 is your primary table then inner join for each user id against tbl 1 so each record returns multiple rows then just where clause tbl1.user_id vs the passed in id and it'll return what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t1.id as id, t1.name, t1.email, t2a.profile_value as class, t2b.profile_value as phone
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2a ON t2a.user_id = t1.id AND t2a.profile_key = 'profile.klasse'
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2b ON t2b.user_id = t1.id AND t2b.profile_key = 'profile.phone'
```

Comment: AFAICR on MySQL, table aliases might need the AS keyword. `LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2a` but I'm not sure anymore

Comment: You are right I should have used a second look, fixed it

Comment: @Eloims your recollection is flawed

Comment: Thank's a lot for Your help! What if I only want to show rows where profile_value equals eg '10A' - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two joins with specific `profile_key` values:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.email, t2.profile_value AS class, t3.provile_value AS phone
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.user_id AND t2.profile_key='profile.klasse')
LEFT JOIN Table2 t3 ON (t1.id = t3.user_id AND t3.profile_key='profile.phone')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a database query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem :

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.`name`,
    t1.email,
    CASE t2.profile_key
        WHEN 'profile.klasse' THEN t2.profile_value
    END AS 'class',
    (SELECT profile_value FROM table2 WHERE profile_key = 'profile.phone' AND user_id = t1.id) AS 'phone'
FROM
    table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id AND t2.profile_key = 'profile.klasse' ORDER BY id;
```

Click [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dca4/1/0)

Comment: Thank You very much - I will play around with Your suggestion.

Comment: What if I want to show rows where profile_value equals '10A'? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or, slower but simpler...

```
SELECT t1.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t2.profile_key = 'profile.klasse' THEN t2.profile_value END) klasse
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t2.profile_key = 'profile.phone' THEN t2.profile_value END) phone
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2 
    ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
 GROUP
    BY t1.user_id
```